# How does Kephas integrate with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, kephas

So much I could understand, Kephas does not provide its own DI container, but it builds adapters on existing ones ([Kephas has its own dependecy injection container. Why another framework, why not use an existing one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103778/kephas-has-its-own-dependecy-injection-container-why-another-framework-why-not?noredirect=1#comment96952935_55103778)). Existing adapters are for System.Composition (MEF2) and, as I learned recently, for Autofac (starting with version 6.5.0, [Cannot use constructors in open generic services with Kephas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623652/cannot-use-constructors-in-open-generic-services-with-kephas/57624812?noredirect=1#comment101704932_57624812)).

However, ASP.NET comes with its own implementation of a DI container. In this regard, is it possible to use Kephas with ASP.NET Core now, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 6.5.0, Kephas will provide also an ASP.NET Core adapter so, yes, it will be shortly possible to use Kephas with ASP.NET Core. However, the built-in Dependency Injection does not have all the features Kephas requires, naming metadata and lazy instantiation. There will also be an adapter for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, but without the aforementioned functionality, so I do not really recommend it. The Autofac adapter is the recommended one (event the Microsoft ASP.NET Core recommends it for advanced scenarios).

On the other hand, you could let Kephas manage its dependencies using MEF2 or Autofac and provide to ASP.NET Core a service provider aggregating the default one (or the one of your choice) and the one from Kephas. This has the following drawbacks:

1. You will end up with two containers.
2. The Kephas container will not have access to the services provided by ASP.NET Core.

Comment: The second suggestion looks more like a temporary workaround. I would take then the Autofac adapter, it seems more future proof to me.